# Remove the Rotate icon in Syncfusion WinRT Diagram

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, syncfusion

Hi, I need to develop an WinRT app with XAML and I'm using Syncfusion's library for that. Whenever I click on a node the resizer appears along with the rotate icon. I removed all the QuickCommands but the rotate icon won't go away.

Please note that I am using the SfDiagram inside a custom control. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are glad to announce that our Essential Studio 2015 Volume 1 is rolled out and is available for download under the following link:
http://www.syncfusion.com/forums/118723/essential-studio-2015-volume-1-final-release-v13-1-0-21-available-for-download 
Feature Information:
Requirement: Remove the Rotate Icon from Node
We have provided support to achieve your requirement in our Essential Studio 2015 Volume 1.This requirement can be achieved by using SelectorConstraints property of ISelector. We have provided code snippet to represent this. Please refer to the following code snippet 
Code Snippet:

```
(DiagramControl.SelectedItems as ISelector).SelectorConstraints = (DiagramControl.SelectedItems as ISelector).SelectorConstraints & ~SelectorConstraints.Rotator;
```

Here, DiagramControl is the instance of SfDiagram.

We thank you for your support and appreciate your patience in waiting for this release. Please get in touch with us if you would require any further assistance.

Regards,
Syncfusion Support Team